# Equation RandomForest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am currently working on machine learning models and in particular on the RandomForest model. For the moment, I managed to get the model on a particular dataset. However, later on, I will have to use several datasets. In order to save time, is it possible to get an equation that will allow me to go directly to this model?

I know that a similar question was already asked 7 years ago. However, in the meantime, machine learning has evolved a lot.

Do you have a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Nope. That is the correct answer still.

Comment: "I know that a similar question was already asked 7 years ago." Could you please provide a link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarkoLalovic It is mostly likely this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109002/ (from 2014).